# When will the 2018 FIDE Candidates tournament be held, and who will qualify for it?

Tags: fide, world-championship, candidates

We've just had the World Championship match between Carlsen and Karjakin, so one qualifier for the next Candidates is known: Karjakin.

I assume it will be held in 2018, is anything more known about the date?

What are the rules for qualification of the other players?

Answer (score 21):

The Candidates will be held in **Berlin, Germany, on 10-28 March 2018** ([source](http://www.agonlimited.com/news/2017/9/10/the-fide-world-chess-candidates-tournament-will-take-place-in-berlin-germany-on-march-10-28-2018)).

According to [FIDE's Rules & Regulations for the Candidates Tournament of the FIDE World Championship cycle 2016-2018](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=145&view=article), the following will qualify, in order of priority:

**1. The loser of the previous World Championship Match -- Sergey Karjakin.**

**2. The 2 finalists of the FIDE World Cup 2017 - Ding Liren and Levon Aronian.**

This is a 128-player knockout tournament, currently being held from **1 to 25 September 2017**, in Batumi, Georgia, with the final in Tbilisi, Georgia (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_World_Cup_2017), which also has details about qualifiers to the World Cup that go too far for this answer).

Karjakin and Carlsen played the World Cup so a situation could have arisen where a player not in the final would qualify, but they were both eliminated.

Quarter finals:

- **Maxime Vachier-Lagrave** beat Peter Svidler 2.5 - 1.5
- **Wesley So** beat Vladimir Fedoseev 1.5 - 0.5
- **Ding Liren** beat Richard Rapport 1.5 - 0.5
- **Levon Aronian** beat Vassily Ivanchuk 1.5 - 0.5

Semi-finals:

- **Levon Aronian** beat Maxime Vachier-Lagrave 5-4
- **Ding Liren** beat Wesley So 3.5 - 2.5

Final (not relevant for the Candidates, but for completeness):

- **Levon Aronian** beat Ding Liren 4-2

**3. The top 2 winners of the FIDE Grand Prix 2016/2017.**

There are four events:

- 18-27 February 2017, in Sharjah, United Arab Emirates
- 12-21 May 2017, Moscow, Russia
- 6-15 July 2017, Geneva, Switzerland
- 16-25 November 2017, Palma Majorca, Spain

Top standings after 3 events:

1. **Shakhriyar Mamedyarov** (3/3 events played): 340
2. **Alexander Grischuk** (3/3): 336 3/7
3. Teimour Radjabov (2/3): 241 3/7
4. Maxime Vachier-Lagrave (2/3): 211 3/7

(players with 3 events and insufficient points left out)

**4. The 2 players not otherwise qualified with the highest average rating (among those that participated in the WC or GP).**

Calculated using the 12 rating lists from january 1 to december 1, 2017.

```
| Name                      | Avg  | Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr | May | June| July| Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov |
|---------------------------|------|------|------|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Caruana, Fabiano          | 2808 | 2827 | 2827 | 2817 | 2817| 2802| 2808| 2807| 2807| 2799| 2794| 2799|
| So, Wesley                | 2806 | 2808 | 2822 | 2822 | 2822| 2815| 2812| 2810| 2810| 2792| 2788| 2788|
|---------------------------|------|------|------|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Vachier-Lagrave, Maxime   | 2796 | 2796 | 2796 | 2803 | 2803| 2795| 2796| 2791| 2789| 2804| 2794| 2796|
| Mamedyarov, Shakhriyar    | 2786 | 2766 | 2766 | 2772 | 2772| 2772| 2800| 2800| 2797| 2797| 2791| 2802|
| Nakamura, Hikaru          | 2785 | 2785 | 2785 | 2793 | 2793| 2798| 2785| 2792| 2792| 2781| 2774| 2780|
| Anand, Viswanathan        | 2785 | 2786 | 2786 | 2786 | 2786| 2786| 2786| 2783| 2783| 2794| 2783| 2783|
```

**5. One organiser's nominee.**

**[Vladimir Kramnik](http://www.agonlimited.com/news/2017/10/29/vladimir-kramnik-nominated-as-wild-card-choice-to-the-fide-world-chess-candidates-tournament)** was chosen as the wildcard.

This could have been player with a rating of 2725 or higher in one of the rating lists in 2017.

*Next update: the final Grand Prix, result 25 november.*

Comment: They theoretically can, but only in really unlikely cases -- they have to win the last event outright (170 points), most the others above them should get 0 points (really unlikely) and Mamedyarov and/or Grischuk needs to qualify through the World Cup.

Comment: Just a guess: if Aronian doesn't qualify either by World Cup or by rating, he still have a good chance to be picked as the organiser's nominee, having strong ties with Germany and being obviously legitimate due to his place in the world top 10 for about a decade. Otherwise, former world champions Kramnik and Anand are also good candidates-to-picked-as-candidates too.

Comment: @OlivierPucher What in my opinion should count a bit against Aronian is that he already got the wildcard last time. I'd think all of Caruana, So, Kramnik should play as those are *very* close in rating average.(Aronian has no chance at all to qualify via rating.) Current projections have So and Kramnik at near equality a tad behind Caruana. Thus, if So does not make it via WC the third of those three should be picked, IMO.

Comment: @TMM: As far as I can see, they neglected to put it in the actual rules, but there's no way he'll be allowed in.

Comment: Time for an update ! Already qualified: Karjakin, Ding, Aronian. 2 rating spots: tight race between So, Caruan and Kramnik. 2 GP spots: tight race between Mamedyarov, Grischuk, Radjabov and MVL. 1 wild card: anyone guess (Annad, Kramnik, MVL, ...)

Comment: If the race is so tight, I wonder if one player trailing by a couple of rating points might be tempting to play in a weak open without price at the end of december just to gain some rating points. Imagine Caruana in a Xmas open, scoring 9/9 vs an opposition of players below 2200: that would gain him about 10 elo points, which is almost one average point for the jan17-dec17 period. Can a spot in the candidates be decided by such a trick ? Suddently elo rating can make a huge difference...

Answer (score 9):

According to [Agon](http://www.agonlimited.com/calendar/2018/11/8/candidates-tournament-2018) (who owns the rights), it will take place from March 8 to March 29, 2018.

I don't think anything else is known at this point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, finalist from the previous cycle is one of the candidates; two more spots go to the latest World Cup winner and runner-up, a couple of spots are determined by Grand Prix results, one spot is the host's choice (that's how Aronian got into the last Candidates), and the rest are determined by the FIDE rating list. That is, more or less, what was used for the last tournament - I don't know if that's subject to change or not.

Comment: Do you have a reference/source for this?